# ViewData returns null instead of a tuple of lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, viewdata

Hellow,

I'm using ASP.NET CORE with Razor Pages and I'm trying to go through the final step of making my ViewData return a tuple of lists.
I made things work the way I wanted, where I made 2 different ViewDatas return 2 lists, but the order of it wasn't the way I wanted, so I put them both in a tuple to return the 2 lists one after another, subject, text, subject, text, etc.

Creating and adding data to the tuple in my Services Class:

```
    public Tuple<List<string>, List<JToken>> get_data_om_mig_info_data()
    {
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(json_file_name);
        JToken data = JToken.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
        JObject om_mig_info = data["om_mig_info"].Value<JObject>();
        List<string> subjects = om_mig_info.Properties().Select(property => property.Name).ToList();
        List<JToken> text = om_mig_info.Properties().Select(property => property.Value).ToList();

        Tuple<List<string>, List<JToken>> om_mig_data = new Tuple<List<string>, List<JToken>>(subjects, text);
        return om_mig_data;
    }
```

Index.cs:
Here Tuuple gets all the items as intended. Item1 Count = 3, and Item2 Count = 3.
But the ViewData remains null.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public string Index_title { get; private set; }
    public Data_Info_Service Om_mig_service_text { get; set; }
    public Tuple<List<string>, List<JToken>> Tuuple { get; set; }
    public object aaa;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, Data_Info_Service Om_mig_service_text)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        this.Om_mig_service_text = Om_mig_service_text;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Tuuple = Om_mig_service_text.get_data_om_mig_info_data(); // Tuple works
        ViewData["data_text"] = Tuuple;
        aaa = ViewData["data_text"]; // aaa seems to work as well, has all items
        Index_title = "Om mig";
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="data_position">
    @foreach (var data in ViewData["data_text"] as IEnumerable<Tuple<List<string>, List<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>>>) // Exception here
    {
        <h5>@data</h5>
    }
</div>
```

Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

(... as System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>, 
System.Collections.Generic.List<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>>>) returned null.
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're adding a single tuple into `ViewData["data_text"]`, yet you're doing `... as IEnumerable<...>` in your view. If you want it to be a collection, construct a collection and add the single tuple to it before storing it into ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be working :

```
public void OnGet()
{
    Var datas = ViewData["data_text"] as Om_mig_service_text.get_data_om_mig_info_data();}
```

Comment: Can you use `as` followed by a method invocation? The method invocation is an expression and leads to a _value_, but I think `as` needs a _type_.

Comment: The method invocation is returning a `Tuple<>` of multiple things, I guess it might work, but if it doesn't you can easily do `Tuuple = Om_mig.....` and then `var datas = ViewData["data_text"] as Tuuple`

Comment: No. You should get a compile-time error similar to `error CS0118: 'Tuuple' is a variable but is used like a type`. You can never use a value as a type like that. Compare [this simple example](https://tio.run/##VYwxCoAwEAT7vOJKBX2B@ATBwsbyPEOIaAK5M43k7TEBG6uBmWWJe2LKmQXFEtCJzDAHbwJe6lGfjt7uMKF1TVtkUj@/aJbGb4cmgYIOWIJ1pqKuIwYgdKu/YawdkGsayk3K@QU "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online").

Answer (score 0):

The cast in your View is not valid.
You cannot cast a Tuple containing 2 lists into a single list.

```
<div class="data_position">
@{
   var data = ViewBag.data_text;
   var list1 = data.Item1 as List<string>;
   var list2 = data.Item2 as List<string>;
}
@foreach (var item in list1)
{
    <h5>@item</h5>
}
</div>
```